# Spark MLlib LogisticRegressionWithLBFGSModel predicts always 1

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, logistic-regression

I am a newbie in ML and I am trying my hands out. So here is the problem I am facing -

I have a dataset which looks like this  -

```
1,32,89
0,2,6
1,71,87
0,2,3
1,2,67
1,78,46
1,25,15
1,18,11
1,8,5
1,7,5
1,3,2
1,3,2
1,2,2
1,2,2
1,926,61
0,99,7
1,42,3
0,18,2
0,15,1
0,13,1
0,11,1
0,11,1
0,9,1
0,8,1
0,8,1
0,7,1
0,7,1
0,7,1
1,7,1
0,6,1
0,6,1
0,6,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,5,100
1,263,90
0,6,3
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,307,73
0,16,4
1,5,2
0,4,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
1,14,88
1,95,74
1,14,11
1,8,7
0,2,2
1,8,73
1,2,19
1,7,78
1,5,42
1,3,25
1,344,68
1,27,6
1,7,2
1,7,2
0,5,1
1,5,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,67
1,116,29
1,71,18
1,68,17
1,54,14
1,20,5
1,15,4
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
1,3,75
1,12,100
1,4,80
0,14,10
0,4,3
0,2,2
0,2,2
0,2,2
1,10,91
1,9,75
0,2,17
1,1947,88
1,23,2
0,5,1
1,5,1
1,4,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,1900,85
1,32,2
1,19,1
1,11,1
1,10,1
0,8,1
0,8,1
0,6,1
0,6,1
0,6,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
1,4,1
1,4,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,445,85
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2648,86
0,18,1
0,15,1
0,9,1
0,8,1
0,7,1
0,7,1
0,7,1
0,6,1
0,6,1
0,6,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,66,10
1,54,8
1,43,7
1,41,7
1,40,6
1,36,6
1,35,6
1,22,4
1,21,4
1,19,3
1,12,2
1,9,2
1,9,2
0,8,2
1,8,2
1,7,2
0,6,1
1,6,1
0,6,1
1,5,1
1,5,1
0,4,1
1,4,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
1,796,25
1,394,13
1,156,5
1,134,5
1,104,4
1,89,3
1,86,3
1,84,3
1,70,3
1,56,2
1,48,2
1,43,2
1,38,2
1,37,2
1,34,2
1,32,1
1,30,1
1,29,1
1,24,1
1,24,1
1,23,1
0,21,1
1,20,1
1,20,1
1,20,1
1,17,1
1,17,1
1,15,1
1,14,1
1,13,1
1,13,1
1,13,1
1,13,1
0,12,1
1,12,1
1,11,1
1,10,1
1,9,1
0,9,1
0,8,1
0,8,1
0,8,1
1,8,1
1,8,1
1,7,1
1,7,1
1,7,1
0,6,1
1,6,1
1,5,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
1,5,1
0,5,1
1,5,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
1,5,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
1,4,1
1,4,1
0,4,1
1,4,1
0,4,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
1,62,92
1,3,60
1,14,94
1,13,87
1,2,67
1,361,91
0,13,4
1,4,100
1,181,44
1,116,29
1,27,7
1,22,6
1,8,2
1,8,2
0,7,2
0,3,1
0,3,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
1,3857,64
1,976,17
1,252,5
1,122,3
1,64,2
1,61,2
1,59,1
1,31,1
1,12,1
1,10,1
1,8,1
1,8,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
0,5,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,4,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
1,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,3,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
1,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
0,2,1
```

Now, I have this following spark code that I am running (it is an RDD Based code as I am using spark-1.6)

```
"""
Logistic Regression With LBFGS Example.
"""
from __future__ import print_function

from pyspark import SparkContext
# $example on$
from pyspark.mllib.classification import LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS, LogisticRegressionModel
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint

# $example off$
import pymongo_spark


if __name__ == "__main__":

    feature_names = ["times", "percentage"]

    sc = SparkContext(appName="LBFGSLOgisticRegressionForRaphael")

    # $example on$
    # Load and parse the data
    def parsePoint(line):
        values = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')]
        return LabeledPoint(values[0], values[1:])

    def mapper(p):
        ret = (p.label, model.predict(p.features))
        print(ret)
        return ret


    data = sc.textFile("/home/ubuntu/etl-scripts/parameters.csv")
    trainingSet = data.map(parsePoint)
    # Build the model
    model = LogisticRegressionWithLBFGS.train(trainingSet)


    #Evaluating the model on training data
    labelsAndPreds = trainingSet.map(mapper)
    # trainErr = labelsAndPreds.filter(lambda (v, p): v != p).count() / float(parsedData.count())
    # print("Training Error = " + str(trainErr))

    # # Save and load model
    # model.save(sc, "target/tmp/pythonLogisticRegressionWithLBFGSModel")
    # sameModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load(sc,
    #                                          "target/tmp/pythonLogisticRegressionWithLBFGSModel")
    # $example off$
```

The file that I am loading (parameters.csv) is the file having the training data I posted above. Now the print statement in mapper function always prints 1 whatever the parameters are. Which means it is always predicting positive. I have no idea what I am missing here? What is the reason that when applied the model on the very training set itself from where it had learned it predicts completely wrong?

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your data contains lots of duplicates and lots of uncertainties. e.g 1, 2, 1 and 0, 2, 1. This doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I kind of understand the problem now with the help of this comment.